# javascript escaped string is not getting unescaped with c# regex.Unescape()

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, escaping

I am sending an escaped string from JavaScript to c# controller and now I want it to unescape in `c#`.

I used `regex.Unescape()` in `c#` but its not working. So, how I will unescape it in `c#`?

Comment: Can you escape the same String in C# and in javascript? what is the result of each string? Can you post this?

Comment: How are you escaping the string with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Uri.Unescape` or `UnescapeDataString`, see [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescape.aspx#Y166)

Comment: thanks for answer but it not working showing exception Invalid URI and i am sending the "<head><link...<link..<script.." this kind of string from javascript

Comment: Maybe you should try using `URIEncodeComponent` client side, instead of `escape`

Comment: @Ates Goral, yep. Sorry, wasn't concentrated, working on a few things at once.

Answer (score 0):

If you need `Unicode` support and you are not able to use the `unescape` functionality implemented in `System.Web`, you can use the following replace statement instead:

```
string str = "%u0442%u043E%u0432%u0430%20%u0435%20text%20%14%u20AC";

//replace Unicode characters
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"%U([0-9A-F]{4})",  match => ((char)int.Parse( match.Groups[1].Value, NumberStyles.HexNumber ) ).ToString(),RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );
//now replace ASCII character
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"%([0-9A-F]{2})",  match => ((char)int.Parse( match.Groups[1].Value, NumberStyles.HexNumber ) ).ToString(),RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );

Console.WriteLine(str);
```